# Trying to solve error: Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I know this question has been asked many times, and I have scoured those answers for a potential solution to what is happening with my code to no avail. So here goes.

I have a page with an update panel. On this update panel I have a button that generates a Telerik pdf report and downloads it. However, when clicking the button I get the notorious error: Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent.

Here is my code (simplified for ease of posting this question:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnPayrollDetails);
}

    protected void btnPayrollDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PayPeriod pay = GetPeriod();
    if (pay == null || (pay.Expenses.Count == 0 && pay.Invoices.Count == 0))
    {
        return;
    }
    var file = "test";
    var report = new Core.Reports.PayrollDetails(Global.Account.Member.ID, pay, mypMonth.SelectedDate.Value);
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.RenderingResult result = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor().RenderReport("PDF", report, null);
    this.Response.DownloadFile(result.DocumentBytes, file + ".pdf");
}
```

The call to this.Response.DownloadFile calls an extension method here:

```
public static void DownloadFile(this HttpResponse Response, byte[] fileBytes, string fileName, string mime = "application/pdf")
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.ContentType = mime;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes)) { ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream); }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
}
```

The baffling part is I have this exact same code running in other projects and it works absolutely without any issues. So, if anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this issue bugged me for a really long time until I stumbled across a solution.

For any of you that is having a similar problem to this here is what finally worked for me.

I removed the `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnPayrollDetails);` from the Page_Load() event and added it to the button_Init event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPayrollDetails" runat="server" Text="Payroll Details" OnClick="btnPayrollDetails_Click" OnInit="btnPayrollDetails_Init" />

protected void btnPayrollDetails_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnPayrollDetails);
}
```

For some reason the button was not getting registered to the script manager and moving it from the PageLoad() to the buttons Init() method fixed this issue.

Comment: This was not my exact problem, but to my great surprise, this led me to the answer. If I did not do the RegisterPostbackControl correctly, I got the Cannot Set Content Type .... error, even though the Response.HeadersWritten was false at the point of Response.AddHeader